# How to formatting a print of a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I use this...

```
IO.println( Arrays.deepToString( array ) );
```

to print my Array on the Screen. The result:

```
[[., ., ., ., ., ., .], [., ., ., ., ., ., .], [., ., ., ., ., ., .], [., ., .,
., ., ., .], [., ., ., ., ., ., .]]
```

My problem, I want it would looking like this:

```
[[., ., ., ., ., ., .], 
 [., ., ., ., ., ., .], 
 [., ., ., ., ., ., .], 
 [., ., ., ., ., ., .], 
 [., ., ., ., ., ., .]]
```

Can you help me to find a way to format this "print of an array"?

Thank you very much!

and sorry for my english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
IO.println(Arrays.deepToString(array).replace("], [", "],\n ["));
```

Thus replacing every `], [` by `],\n [` whereas `\n` adds a newline to the string.

Comment: You'll want a space after the `\n` to match the OP's sample output.

Answer (score 0):

add \n between the segments

```
System.out.println([[.,.,.], \n [[.,.,.], \n .......);
```

as you continue the pattern each \n starts a new line

Edit: result of that code would be:  (also dont use the format just use your array and array number ie: `System.out.println(array[1] /n array[2] /n array[3]`

[[.,.,.],

[[.,.,.],

.........

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
To do this, was one of my first trys... 

The problem is that I dont know the "size of the array". Thats why I use the deepToString method. And I dont found a way to tell this method to use "/n" between the rows

Comment: array.length with no parenthesis will tell you the array length, the /n should be \n sorry